Can we find an orthogonal family in an $n$-dimensional space with more than $n$ vectors in unusual algebraic systems?
Can we find an orthogonal family in a space of dimension $n$ with more than $n$ (non-null) vectors?
I know that the answer is no in the fields of real numbers and complex numbers. But what about other spaces, such as the skew field of quaternions, or the space of octonions?
For example, it is known that in the Sedenion systems that there exist divisors of $0$ (wikipedia:sedenion). As a consequence, we can find $2$ orthogonal 1-D vectors.
With octonions and quaternions, there are no divisors of $0$, but is it possible to build more than $n$ orthogonal $n$-D vectors?

What do you mean by orthogonal? If you mean "orthogonal with respect to some nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form", then no, because a maximal set of pairwise orthogonal vectors is a basis, regardless of base field.

I mean orthogonal with respect to the usual scalar product. This reasoning also works with quaternions and octonions even if they do not form a field?

Yes, the field/ring/algebra structure is absolutely irrelevant. This is just a matter of vector spaces equipped with bilinear forms.

Note the "nondegenerate" condition is key in Nicholas' comment.
